# Rails 5.2 with master.key Digital Ocean deployment: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have migrated my Ruby on Rails application from Rails 5.1.2 to Rails 5.2.0 to use the encrypted secrets. Application is successfully deployed to Digital Ocean Ubuntu Server. But when I go in browser to access, it shows the following log.

```
    ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
  /home/deploy/apps/GeekyCricket/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:206:in `rescue in _decrypt'
  /home/deploy/apps/GeekyCricket/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:184:in `_decrypt'
  /home/deploy/apps/GeekyCricket/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:157:in `decrypt_and_verify'
  /home/deploy/apps/GeekyCricket/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:21:in `decrypt_and_verify'
  /home/deploy/apps/GeekyCricket/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:79:in `decrypt'
  /home/deploy/apps/GeekyCricket/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:42:in `read'
  /home/deploy/apps/GeekyCricket/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
  /home/deploy/apps/GeekyCricket/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
  /home/deploy/apps/GeekyCricket/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:38:in `options'
  /home/deploy/apps/GeekyCricket/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:271:in `method_missing'
  (erb):12:in `<main>'
```

I have added encrypted secrets using `rails credentials:edit`, which creates `config/credentials.yml.enc` and `master.key`.

I also have added the master.key file on `/app_name/shared/config/` on my ubuntu server, also placed an env variable `RAILS_MASTER_KEY`. But still getting this error, I don't know what I am missing here.

Comment: Could you make the answer is the correct answer if it solved your problem, @talha-junaid? Otherwise, I'm ready to help you.

Comment: Did you solve it? I really wanna help you about it.

Comment: Did you solve it? I really wanna help you about it. Thx

Comment: Thanks @Boris, I Solved it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution A and B are different solutions. Just choose which is good for you.

## a. Deploy from Continous Integration

1. Edit `deploy.rb`

```
set :default_env, {
  "RAILS_ENV" => "production",
  "RAILS_MASTER_KEY" => ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
}
```

2. Add `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` as a variable

- [Travis CI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-Variables-in-Repository-Settings)
- [GitLab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#variables)

## b. Usage of `master.key`

1. Edit `deploy.rb`

```
append :linked_files, "config/master.key"
```

2. Upload `master.key` with `:linked_files`

Let's assume our application's root path is `/home/deploy/awesome-project`. All we need to do is upload the key file to `/home/deploy/awesome-project/shared/config/master.key`.

Comment: sorry for not replying you earlier.I already have solved the issue. But i don't think that default_env is  good way as ultimately we have to push the `deploy.rb` on gitlab/github and our master key can be exposed, we definitely don't want to do that. Although, this would be good `set :default_env, {
  "RAILS_MASTER_KEY" => ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
}`

Comment: You're right, @talha-junaid. So, I'm going to change my answer.

Comment: @TalhaJunaid : Could you please post your answer here? It will be helpful. I'm also getting this type of issue and Didn't found any right solution.

Comment: @AkshayBorade, could you check the answer? Thank you.

Comment: @AkshayBorade sorry for not replying you earlier, Does any of the above solution solved your issue?

Comment: May be being daft, but I'm struggling to implement approach B above. I've tried using FileZilla to move the file, but it cannot see the master.key file on my local computer and cannot access the shared/config folder on the server... How would you typically go about moving the file?

Comment: If you delete your repository, you lose your master.key. Please make sure that you have master key under the config folder, @texas.

Comment: Thanks for the response, sorry I wasn't particularly clear - the 'master.key' file is on my local computer (I can open it with Sublime text etc.), I guess there are some settings I need to change in FileZilla to make the file visible.  How do you typically transfer the file - ftp, command line, rake task?

Comment: You should see some characters inside of your `master.key` beacuse it is private which is only you can see.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, when deploying for the first time on my DigitalOcean Droplet, every time I ran `RAILS_ENV=production cap production deploy:initial` it failed complaining this error  - `ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage`

I tried below options which all failed -

- removing `master.key` and `credential.yml.enc` file and then deploying again.
- adding both files again and deploying.

Finally one solution worked, i just added `master.key`, **removing** `credentials.yml.enc` file, committed it and redeployed, and it worked without changing my `deploy.rb` file